# pactdfoundation/pact-broker set up and listening on http://0.0.0.0:9292, but unable to connect

Tags: docker, macos, pact

am running docker container for pactfoundation/pact-broker:latest

- on a mac os x (13.2.1).
- connected to postgres on mac with the right permissions (finally).

Last obstacle: when i try http://0.0.0.0:9292 as from the docker logs (* Listening on http://0.0.0.0:9292), I get "Unable to connect" whether i use firefox, chrome, curl ...

```
*   Trying 0.0.0.0:9292...
* connect to 0.0.0.0 port 9292 failed: Connection refused
* Failed to connect to 0.0.0.0 port 9292 after 6 ms: Couldn't connect to server
* Closing connection 0
curl: (7) Failed to connect to 0.0.0.0 port 9292 after 6 ms: Couldn't connect to server
```

I get the same result with any version of localhost, 127.0.0.1, ...

I know macs can be a pain for connection, so i span up a local fastify server and checked it was reachable, and a docker dynamodb instance and checked its reachable, ....

I could do with a next thing to try, or else a sage word from someone on what I may have not done or missed...

Comment: show us the command you used to run the container

Comment: I am running it from docker desktop with params:
```PACT_BROKER_DATABASE_URL = postgres://pact_broker:{pwd}@docker.for.mac.localhost/pact_broker```
and just out of frustration (because i failed to connect) added the port for the docker (but still at 9292):
```PACT_BROKER_PORT = 9292```

Comment: sounds like pact is in one docker container, postgres in another.  They will each have their own `localhost`, and won't use the mac's.  https://docs.docker.com/network/network-tutorial-standalone/ you might also consider looking at docker-compose which can simplify running multiple containers https://docs.docker.com/compose/

Comment: Actually postgres in on the Mac not in a container, but using docker.for.mac.localhost got it connected (found that in another stack overflow post). I will take a look at the links you suggested though (did read through the docker compose option in pact foundation readme)

Answer (score 1):

ok - found a command line option from [stackoverflow azure pactbroker docker connect question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67957118/how-to-connect-the-pact-broker-to-a-local-or-cloud-instance-of-postgresql)

```
docker run -e PACT_BROKER_DATABASE_USERNAME=pact_broker \
-e PACT_BROKER_DATABASE_URL=postgres://pact_broker:$password@docker.for.mac.localhost/pact_broker \
-e PACT_BROKER_DATABASE_NAME=pact_broker \
-e PACT_BROKER_DATABASE_PORT=5432 \
-p 9292:9292 \
pactfoundation/pact-broker:latest
```

This has things up and running fine. Will have a further read, try adding some settings in docker desktop to see where it didnt work (if i find that will add it here to tie things off), and then follow @erik258 advice on docker compose...